# How to execute discord.py loop task

Tags: python, discord.py

This is my code but I cant get the loop to work.

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import tasks, commands
client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('!test'):
        await message.channel.send('Working')

@tasks.loop(seconds = 10)
async def myLoop():
      channel = client.get_channel(899698630271856640)
      await channel.send('1')
```

Comment: Make sure to start the loop (`myLoop.start()`) later in your code, before calling `run` on your bot.

Answer (score 0):

To start a discord.py loop, you must run it under the `on_ready` function. Add `myLoop.run()` in the function.